# When I ask Python to multiply a number by 100, it prints the number 100 times?

Tags: python, math

For example, when I enter `2 * 100`, I get:
 `5555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555`

Why is this? 
Here is my code

```
import math
KeepProgramRunning = True
while KeepProgramRunning:
    print 'Please enter the centimetre value you wish to convert to millimetres '
    a = raw_input()
    print 'The answer is',
```

Comment: I see nothing there that requires the `math` module

Comment: I know that variable names are subjective, but KeepProgramRunning is simply awful.. just use while running:

Answer (score 10):

That's because `raw_input()` returns a string

Use `int()` to convert that string to an integer:

```
a = int(raw_input())
```

example:

```
>>> x = raw_input()
2
>>> x * 5
'22222'
>>> x = int(raw_input())
2
>>> x * 5
10
```

Answer (score 7):

That because input retrieve a string, do as here:

```
import math
KeepProgramRunning = True
while KeepProgramRunning:
    print 'Please enter the centimetre value you wish to convert to millimetres '
    a = int(raw_input())
    print 'The answer is',
```

Comment: I've just checked the upper code, probably he need it for something else.